# how to export mysql's data to browser with saving memory in golang web application

Tags: go, http, web, pipeline, data-stream

sometimes maybe data is huge in mysql,so hope to save memory to export data to browser in go web application,I guess application/octet-stream is a good way but don't how to do it.
so how to select data from mysql while at the same time export data to the browser?

I tried csv ,but it's first select all data from mysql to memory then export to the front end,thus would cause  out of memory,hope get help.

Comment: There appears to be several questions mixed into one. Do you imply there is a backend server (written in Go) which queries MySQL for data by request of a client performing a HTTP request to this server, and in response the server is supposed to deliver that data from MySQL to the client with as little buffering as possible–"piping" or "streaming" it? If yes, is that data supposed to be somehow _processed_ by the client–say, by a front-end JS/WASM code running in the browser, or is that data is supposed to be merely displayed by the browser "as is", as it's being fetched from the server?

Comment: yes, users use browser then request to go server, go server fetch data from mysql then response to browser with a csv file or excel file,now my solve way is fetching all data from mysql to go server's memory,it's here may cause out of memory,because sometimes data is hug.  I hope there is a way that I fetch 100 records from mysql and at the same time transfer them to browser until all data needed fetched from mysql finished.

Comment: Please tag the user whose comment you're responding to using the `@` sign–like `@user`, otherwise they won't get notified (I've just happened to follow your question; few folks do that).

Comment: If there is buffering on the server you must have explicitly written it to do that. Neither the database/sql nor encoding/csv packages do that on their own.